# Call child method in main class in react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a child class to render an Alert with some variables.
I make myAlert.js file and import it in the main.js

here are my codes:

```
// main.js


onLoginPressed() {
// Call showAlert from child
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableHighlight
         onPress = {this.onLoginPressed.bind(this)}
       />
    </View>
  )
}
```

and now myAlert.js:

```
// myAlert.js


export default class myAlert extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
  super();
  }

render() {
const {showAlert} = this.state;

  return (
      <View>

        <AwesomeAlert
          showProgress = {false}
          title = "AwesomeAlert"
        />

      </View>
  )
}
}
```

the point is, i want to send "showProgress" and "title" to the child so i can have my customized alert every time is call the child method!

but i get errors...

**1. where is my mistake?**

**2. Should i use redux to control my states in situations like this?**

> thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to call the function of a child. How this is accomplished is managing that state in the parent. So `showAwesomeAlert` should be in the state of `main.js` and passed as a `prop` down to `myAlert.js`. If you need to close it from the child, you'll also need to pass down a function to toggle the state in the parent.

In the following example I manage the state of whether the alert is active in the parent, `parent`. I also pass a function which toggles whether it's active so from the popup I can call that to disable it.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { childAlertActive: false };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({ childAlertActive: !this.state.childAlertActive });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>Toggle child alert</button>
        <Child alertActive={this.state.childAlertActive} toggle={this.toggle} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const Child = ({ alertActive, toggle }) => (
  <SomeAlert 
    active={alertActive}
    toggle={toggle}
  />
);
```

Comment: Let me know if you need a code example of this concept!

Comment: would be great if you add an example please... (and should i use redux for these cases in my app?)

Comment: I wouldn't personally use redux, and even less so for very minor state management like forms/popups. Don't feel pressured to ever need it

Comment: You don't need to use redux at all for a situation like this. You can easily handle this using @JLivengood example.

Comment: this example isn't working in react-native!
could you please make a look again?